# Enable PVC protection via Helm

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

One can set for K8s:

```
kubeletArguments:
  feature-gates:
  - PVCProtection=true
```

I'd like to configure this with Helm. Can I set this in Helm so my PVC is protected for any deleting operation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, sorry.  Anything labeled "kubelet" or "feature gate" is cluster-level configuration and not something you can include in an application-level Helm chart.